# Retrieve values from excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel

Hey guys I have made a excel file in 1997 to 2003 format and I am trying to read the value from the excel sheet but it is throwing "External table is not in the expected format." error. I have got installed microsoft 2013 office in my machine.

```
        var fileName = @"C:\Users\Abhineet\Documents\True XL.xls.";
        var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\""; ;
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            var sheets = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] ";

                var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                var ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
    }
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

you can try this ,replace you command text line by this one:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheets + "] ";
```

Comment: Throwing error External table is not in the expected format